# HikariCP: migration from BoneCP and analyze benchmark data

Tags: jdbc, benchmarking, connection-pooling, vmware, hikaricp

I'm testing a migration from BoneCP to HikariCP.

The results of the benchmark ([HikariCP Benchmark](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP-benchmark)) are these:

```
Benchmark                                 (maxPoolSize)  (pool)   Mode  Samples      Score  Score error   Units
c.z.h.b.ConnectionBench.cycleCnnection               32  hikari  thrpt       16   1033,071       38,893  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.ConnectionBench.cycleCnnection               32    bone  thrpt       16   1648,954       42,610  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.ConnectionBench.cycleCnnection               32  tomcat  thrpt       16    592,838       21,709  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.ConnectionBench.cycleCnnection               32    c3p0  thrpt       16    125,857        3,666  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.ConnectionBench.cycleCnnection               32   vibur  thrpt       16    831,693        9,299  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.StatementBench.cycleStatement                32  hikari  thrpt       16  49983,959     4796,385  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.StatementBench.cycleStatement                32    bone  thrpt        8   7022,146      526,111  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.StatementBench.cycleStatement                32  tomcat  thrpt       16  28777,731     1011,316  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.StatementBench.cycleStatement                32    c3p0  thrpt       16   3367,641      137,937  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.StatementBench.cycleStatement                32   vibur  thrpt       16   1739,060       45,451  ops/ms
```

I suppose that a higher Score is better, so:

- Why is cycleConnection lower in HikariCP than BoneCP?
- Are the cycleStatement results enough better to migrate to HikariCP, taking into account the cycleConnection results?
- What does Score Error column mean?

Any tip, advice, etc. in these topics or related migration to HikariCP are very helpful for me.

Thanks a lot

**FIRST UPDATING**:

@brettw , thank you for your suggestions, and congratulations for your great job.

I did a full run last night with *nohup ./benchmark.sh &* and got these results:

```
Benchmark                                 (maxPoolSize)  (pool)   Mode  Samples      Score  Score error   Units
c.z.h.b.ConnectionBench.cycleCnnection               32  hikari  thrpt      150    965,017       27,307  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.ConnectionBench.cycleCnnection               32    bone  thrpt      150   1528,097       26,963  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.ConnectionBench.cycleCnnection               32  tomcat  thrpt      150    473,702        8,068  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.ConnectionBench.cycleCnnection               32    c3p0  thrpt      150    108,527        1,591  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.ConnectionBench.cycleCnnection               32   vibur  thrpt      150    740,603       14,556  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.StatementBench.cycleStatement                32  hikari  thrpt       60  47998,292     3112,217  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.StatementBench.cycleStatement                32    bone  thrpt      120   6210,647      110,100  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.StatementBench.cycleStatement                32  tomcat  thrpt      150  25919,389      437,232  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.StatementBench.cycleStatement                32    c3p0  thrpt      150   3074,133       62,629  ops/ms
c.z.h.b.StatementBench.cycleStatement                32   vibur  thrpt      150   1517,554       25,027  ops/ms
```

Reviewing the extended output, I see this exception stack trace 6 times in the log:

```
Iteration  15: [com.zaxxer.hikari.benchmark.StatementBench.cycleStatement-jmh-worker-7] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariCP pool HikariPool-0 is shutting
down.


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to remove an object from the bag that was not borrowed or reserved
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.ConcurrentBag.remove(ConcurrentBag.java:207)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.closeConnection(HikariPool.java:394)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.releaseConnection(HikariPool.java:223)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.ConnectionProxy.close(ConnectionProxy.java:216)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.benchmark.StatementBench$ConnectionState.teardown(StatementBench.java:63)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.benchmark.generated.StatementBench_cycleStatement.cycleStatement_Throughput(StatementBench_cycleStatement.java:100)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.LoopBenchmarkHandler$BenchmarkTask.call(LoopBenchmarkHandler.java:204)
        at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.LoopBenchmarkHandler$BenchmarkTask.call(LoopBenchmarkHandler.java:186)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Finally, I answer you other topics from your post:

- pom.xml was updated for quick and full executions.
- It couldn't be possible to execute the test after a clean boot.
- There is a Tomcat server with a web app. The computer neither had high load and no ran heavy process during the test executions.
- JDK version is jdk1.7.0_67
- Linux is x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
- CPU model is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 0 @ 2.90GHz
- Maybe an important issue: Test have been run in a virtual machine, deployed with VMWare.

Thanks again

**SECOND UPDATING**:
The issue about migration has changed to another one about virtualization and benchmarking, which is interesting and useful too.

By now, I have to focus on the virtual environment. When I had a bit of time, I'll run the tests on a *real and direct* environment , and I'll bring here the results.
I bet these tests will show HikariCP as the best connection pool.

@brettw, thank you for your support and your great attitude.

Comment: Are all 8 cores available to the VM?

Comment: @brettw thanks again.
When I execute _more /proc/cpuinfo_ , I get data for _processor       : 0_ and _processor       : 1_ , so my answer is no, this VM instance has 2 cores.

Comment: The [more I read](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018206) about benchmarking on a VMWare instance with a low-level benchmark tool like JMH the more suspicious I am of the result.  Low-level benchmarks are fine, and I would suggest running it on real hardware to satisfy yourself.  But real-life performance is often quite different, so if you have a way to benchmark your application (req/s) using a load test tool, it would probably be better given the virtualized environment.

Answer (score 4):

one of the authors of HikariCP here.  Couple of things to check.  First, it looks like you used the "quick" mode of the benchmark, which we normally use to "smoke test" changes quickly.  I recommend a full run.  The results above look a bit strange, at least on the *cycleStatement* test, as all pools should show *16* (in quick mode) samples but BoneCP is showing only *8*. The full run takes quite a bit of time, but if you just want to compare two pools you can shorten the time quite a bit, like so:

```
./benchmark.sh -p pool=hikari,bone
```

Second, edit the *pom.xml* file for the benchmark and make sure that it is using the latest HikariCP release.  It should be version 2.2.5 (non-SNAPSHOT) now, but the committed pom.xml looks like it still has 2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.

The "Score error" is kind of a standard deviation in samples, it tends to creep higher if there are other processes on the box consuming CPU.  I recommend running the benchmark after a clean boot, after the system as "settled" for a minute or two, and making sure extraneous processes (browsers, etc.) aren't running during the test.

We would be interested in the updated results of your run, as we have yet to see HikariCP score lower than any pool.  Can you also tell us what environment you are running in?  CPU type/cores, OS, Java version, and whether or not this is a virtual machine or not.  Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
How is it even possible for an 8-core E5-2690 to come in with scores so low?  On my desktop i7 Haswell 4-core [I get HikariCP scores](https://gist.github.com/brettwooldridge/19295636f7c47fca83b0) of 23130.760, and Bone scores of 10378.450, vs 965.017 and 1528.097 on the E5-2690?

I am wondering (and researching) whether something like VMWare Hypervisor throttling is kicking in.  I admit I am far from an expert on VM Hypervisors.  In the benchmark HikariCP will definitely punish your CPU.

**UPDATE2:**
Response to comment below.  This issue isn't virtualization, per se.  Virtualization is great and is here to stay.  The issue basically comes down to whether running ***micro***-benchmarks on virtualized hardware is either accurate or meaningful.

I would theorize that, in general, a library that benchmarks higher on *real* hardware will likely perform better on virutalized hardware as well -- even if the same tool cannot be used to measure it there.  That is why above I recommended running a ***macro***-benchmarking tool, such as [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org) against the intended application.  Try it with library A (HikariCP) and library B (BoneCP).  This would hold true for any two libraries.

In summary, running *micro*-benchmark harnesses which take advantage of things like hardware counters etc. can quite possibly yield strange results on virtualized hardware.  This is probably a great topic to bring up in a VMWare forum.

With respect to which library to use, either run JMeter or a similar macro-benchmarking tool or flip a coin.

Comment: I have extended the main post with new data and results. If you want, you can check them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: thank you for your answer again. I adviced against virtualization repeatedly, and sadly, virtual deployment isn't going to change. So, even with these cycleConnection results and considering that cycleStatement results are double better than BoneCP , do you recommend the migration? Can I make another kind of tests? Thanks a lot

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'll try JMeter when I have a bit of time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: another question: how about testing with a profiler like JProfiler? If I get better absolute CPU percentages with HikariCP rather than BoneCP, do you recommend the migration? Thanks again